# Am I training with gpu?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm training a neural model with keras and tensorflow as backend. The log file starts with the following message:

```
nohup: ignoring input
2019-02-12 17:44:29.414526: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2019-02-12 17:44:30.191565: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0
totalMemory: 7.93GiB freeMemory: 7.81GiB
2019-02-12 17:44:30.191601: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-02-12 17:44:30.409790: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-02-12 17:44:30.409828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2019-02-12 17:44:30.409834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
2019-02-12 17:44:30.410015: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7535 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

Does this mean that the training is performed on gpu ?

I would say yes, but when I execute `nvtop`, I see that all the gpu memory is used while 0% of the gpu calculation capacity is used (see yellow screenshot below):

[image: see screenshot]

Also, when I type `htop` in the command line, I see that one CPU is fully used (see black screenshot below)

[image: see screenshot]

How come the gpu memory is used and the cpu capacity calculation is used instead of the gpu capacity calculation  ?

Comment: Are you sure your network started training? Put the logging level of tensorflow to `INFO` and see if it is indeed going through batches without ever raising the usage. A wrongly distributed work between CPU and GPU could result in long periods where the GPU is barely used

Comment: In addition to logging/printing/debugging, you can use [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) directives to enforce operations to run on GPU, so it fails if the GPU cannot be used for some reason (note that some operations, e.g. most of data input, cannot be run on GPU, though, so use it for "pure computation" stuff). It may also be that you input pipeline is taking a lot of time so the GPU is not being fed quickly enough, see [Data Input Pipeline Performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets).

Comment: @bluesummers I think the training began because I have the usual bar `249/508100 [..............................] - ETA: 31:12:33 - loss: 0.5588`

Comment: is the number in the training bar moving? or it stalls each time? if it stalls, it might be a result long CPU computation, making the GPU wait for the CPU to pass data into it

Comment: @bluesummers yes the number in the training bar increases

Comment: It's weird. The behavior I described is hapening for a small dataset, when I do the same with a much larger dataset, only a cpu is used, gpu is barely used (neither the calculation capacyti nor the gpu memory)

Comment: Can't really see what is the problem, last thing I would do will be to increase your batch size by a factor of 100 and see if anything changes, might be that the data is so small you don't actually use the capacity needed to be shown on the nvtop

Comment: @bluesummers unfortunately didn't change much, I changed the batch size from 32 to 512

Comment: Can you link to the network code? Try to wrap some code in it with explicit device allocation `with tf.device(`/device:GPU:0'): ...`

Comment: You should include actual code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have compiled (or you installed already compiled package) tensorflow  with CUDA support, but not with support all instructions available for your CPU (your CPU supports AVX2, AVX512F and FMA instructions that tensorflow can use).

This means, that tensorflow will work fine (with full GPU support), but you can't use your processor at full capacity.

Try compare time (GPU vs CPU) with this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661896/10418812